# Accessing variables in Case Classes

Tags: scala

I have a case class called square and I want to access a variable in it called side. I then want to use pattern matching to detect the object is of type square and return side*side. However when I run the below I get value side is not a member of this object A$A43.this.square

```
case class square(side:Double)

def getArea(o: Object): Double = {
  o match {
     case s: square => s.side*s.side
     case _ => 0
  }
 }
```

Thanks in advance for any advice or assistance.

Comment: You probably want to capitalize your case class and have `case Square(s) => s * s`. Also, you can't return `null` in the catch-all branch because `Double` is a value type.

Comment: @Alec Thanks for that your suggestion worked perfectly, I had 0 in my code I just wrote that on the fly to give an example here. I'll update it now and include a working answer.

Comment: "I then want to use pattern matching to detect the object is of type square and return side*side. " Accepting Object then pattern-matching to find what you really have is a bit of a code smell. Do you really need that?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul The function handles multiple objects so it could be any shape and certain combinations of shapes. I just kept it simple for the example rather than posting 20+ possible getArea instances.

Comment: You might be looking for typeclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was caused by the fact that I was using a non capitalised case classes. So in order to get the above working you would need to do the following.

```
case class Square(side:Double)

def getArea(o: Object): Double = {
  o match {
     case Square(side) => side*side
     //would also be valid case matching syntax
     //case s: Square => s.side * s.side
     case _ => 0
  }
 }
```

Comment: Matching was ok, `case s: Square => s.side * s.side` would also be valid. But it is simpler to use what you have in this post.

Comment: @Łukasz Thanks for the feedback I'll update my answer.